# Posting an array of objects to MongoDB in formData (ValidationError)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I've been struggling to make a POST request to my MongoDB because one of the properties should be an array of objects. I have been following different tutorials but still cannot get my head around it.

I have an array which is an array of objects.

```
tagsArray = [
    { tag_name: "Tiger", ref: "t" },
    { tag_name: "Cheetah", ref: "c" }
];
```

I post it using Fetch API and because it contains an image file, I am using formData. This is how I post it...

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('titleImage', this.state.titleImage);
for (var i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++) {
    formData.append('tags', JSON.stringify(tagsArray[i]));
}

var request = {
    body: formData,
    method: "POST"
}

fetch("http://localhost:3500/posts", request)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
    console.log("Post success:", json);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Moving on, I have created a Schema which you can see here:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tag_name: String,
    ref: String
})

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    titleImage: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: { type: [tagSchema], required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

And this is how I have been trying to save it to my database.

```
exports.create_post = (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new Post({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        titleImage: req.file.path,
        tags: req.body.tags,
    });
    post.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
            post: {
                _id: result._id,
                tags: result.tags
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

This is the error that is logged in the console.

> message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "[
>   \'{"tag_name":"Tiger","ref":"t"}\',\n 
>   \'{"tag_name":"Cheetah","ref":"c"}\' ]" at path "tags"',
>           name: 'CastError',
>           stringValue: '"[ \'{"tag_name":"Tiger","ref":"t"}\',\n  \'{"tag_name":"Cheetah","ref":"c"}\' ]"',
>           kind: 'Array',
>           value: [Array],
>           path: 'tags',
>           reason: [Object] } },   _message: 'Post validation failed',   name: 'ValidationError' }

Answer (score 0):

As always, when I post a question, my competitive spirit and ego brings out new energy and motivation which allows me to focus more and get stuff done. So this is how I solved my problem.

I changed postSchema like this:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    titleImage: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: { type: {tagName: String, tagRef: String}, required: true}
});
```

And few configurations here where I take the array of tags and map it through and converting each string into an object so I can get access to every single property.

```
exports.create_post = (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new Post({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        titleImage: req.file.path,
        tags: req.body.tags.map(tag => {
            var tagObject = JSON.parse(tag);
            return {
                tagName: tagObject.tag_name,
                tagRef: tagObject.ref
            }
        })
    });
    post.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
            post: {
                _id: result._id,
                tags: result.tags.map(tag => {
                    return {
                        tagName: tag.tagName,
                        tagRef: tag.tagRef
                    }
                }),
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

Not sure if the best solution but works fine for me.